# Unable to get dependent object data after form submission in spring MVC

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

```
public class Employee implements IEmployee, Serializable {  

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3539505455231361934L;

@Column(name="emp_Id", nullable=false)
private Integer emp_Id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="login_Id", nullable=false)
private String login_Id;

@Column(name="password", nullable=false)
private String password;

@Column(name="first_name", nullable=false)
private String first_name;

@Column(name="last_name", nullable=false)
private String last_name;

@Column(name="email", nullable=false)
private String email;

@Column(name="address", nullable=false)
private String address;

@Column(name="mobile_Number", nullable=false)
private Integer mobile_Number;

@Column(name="create_Date", nullable=false)
private Date create_Date;

@Column(name="modified_Date", nullable=false)
private Date modified_Date;

@Column(name="security_Question")
private String security_Question;

@Column(name="security_Question_Answer")
private String security_Question_Answer;

@Column(name="login_Attempts")
private String login_Attempts;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="employe_role",
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="login_Id")},
inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_Id")})
private Collection<Role> role;//need to change name --> Dependent Object Role
```

---settters and getters
}

### Role

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="role_Id")
private Integer role_Id;

@Column(name="role_Code", nullable=false)
private String role_Code;

@Column(name="role_Name", nullable=false)
private String role_Name;

@Column(name="discription", nullable=false)
private String discription;

@Column(name="created_Date")
private Date created_Date;

@Column(name="modified_Date")
private Date modified_Date;
```

### JSP form

```
<form:form name="register-employee" action="/registerEmployee" method="post" commandName="employee">
<c:forEach var="role" varStatus="statusEmpRole" items="${employee.role}">

    <form:hidden path="role[${statusEmpRole.index}].role_Name"  value="${role.role_Name}" />
    <form:checkbox path="role[${statusEmpRole.index}].role_Name" value="${role.role_Name}" itemValue="role.role_Id"  /> 
    <c:out value="${role.role_Name}" /><br>
```

### Controller

For displaying the form

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/employeeregistrationform", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView employeeRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, Model map) throws HibernateException, RoleNotFoundException {
    IEmployee iEmployee = new Employee();
    Collection<Role> collectionRoles= IRoleService.getLookUpRoles();
    for (Role role : collectionRoles) {
        LOGGER.info("roel {}",role.getRole_Name());
    }
    iEmployee.setFirst_name("helloooooo");
    iEmployee.setRole(collectionRoles);
     return new ModelAndView("registerEmploye", "employee", iEmployee);  
}
```

Get the Submitted form Data

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/registerEmployee",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee")Employee employee, BindingResult result) {
    LOGGER.info("Registering Employe {}",employee.getFirst_name());
    LOGGER.info("Selected Role Employe {}",employee.getRole());
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();    
    model.setViewName("registerEmploye");
    return model;
}
```

employee.getRole() is getting null
my case is employee having multiple roles. let say admin and Projectmanager. while creating employee admin may select the roles(these are come from database) after submitting the employee registration from i'm getting role object is null.

please help me in this. Am i missing any thing here like property editor or init binder. if so please give me example how to use them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after Google i find the answer

I create Init Binder

```
@InitBinder 
public void bindForm(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Collection.class, new RoleEditor(Collection.class,true));
}
```

And i supply CustomCollectionEditor to that i.e RoleEditor

```
package com.evoke.tms.util;
```

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomCollectionEditor;

import com.evoke.tms.model.Role;

public class RoleEditor extends CustomCollectionEditor {

```
private Set<Role> roles;

public RoleEditor(Class collectionType, boolean nullAsEmptyCollection) {
    super(collectionType, true);
}

public void setValue( Object object ){
    if(object!=null&&object instanceof String)
        System.out.println("Object is of type - " + object.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        String[] roleIds = (String[])object;
        roles=new HashSet<Role>();
        if(roleIds!=null && roleIds.length>0)
        for( int i=0; i<roleIds.length; i++ ){
            try {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(roleIds[i]);
                Role role = new Role();
                role.setRole_Id(id);
                roles.add(role);
            }catch( NumberFormatException ne ){}
        }
    }

public Object getValue(){
    System.out.println("Roles are - " + roles);
    return roles;
}
```

}

And i'm still confused how it is working 
can any one help on this...